# Creating more than one model to Extend Django user

Tags: django

How to link more than one django model to the  authenticated user of a django app .And how will my view.py and html template look like if i want to display information from these models which are link to the user . Thanks in Advance .

Here is my code as follows

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="userprofile")
     experience= model.TextField(max_Length=500,null=True,blank=False)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
     if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=User)
```

Now the second model which  is where i  have a problem

```
class UserProfileDp(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="userprofiledp")
  profile_dp = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_image" ,null= True,blank=True)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.profile_dp
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
if created:
    UserProfileDp.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=User)
```

The form  view of the first model works pretty good without any problem .but i 
  get an error in creating  form  view  for the second model
  Here is my view.py code for the second model

```
def user_profile_pic(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    profile_form = User_dp_form(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.userprofiledp)
    if  profile_form.is_valid():

        profile_form.save()
        messages.success(request,'Your Profile has been Updated')
        return redirect('success:profile_account')
    else:
        messages.error(request,'fill out the fields correctly')
else:

     profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofiledp)
return render(request,"success/user_account/edit_profile.html",{'profile_form':profile_form})
```

Error

RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /user_profile_pic/

User has no userprofiledp.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you link one. Don't overthink it.

Both need a OneToOneField to the user and a related name. There's nothing special in the view and html either. You just reference them both from the user model, the same way you reference fields from one profile model.